What happens when the hostname in a Windows 10 hosts file is an IP address?
Bit of a preamble: I've recently decided to play Assassin's Creed: Director's Cut on my Windows 10 PC. However, the game seemed to regularly freeze, making it unplayable. Based on my searches across different forums, it seemed like the core issue was the game trying to connect to a server which was no longer available.
The solution, repeated across several different forums and wikis was to either disable your internet or add the following hosts file entry:
203.132.26.155 127.0.0.1

Having done so, it worked - the game was no longer repeatedly freezing. Later I've also decided to change it to
203.132.26.155 0.0.0.0

as I've heard that redirecting traffic to 0.0.0.0 tends to fail a bit faster than dumping it at localhost. Nothing changed - the game continued to work as if it was with the previous version of the fix.
However, having finished the game and digging around my hosts file, I realized that:

For the supposed fix of redirecting traffic from 203.132.26.155 to 127.0.0.1 (or 0.0.0.0) the entry was in the wrong order.
You can't redirect one IP to the other via a hosts file, just map host names to IP addresses.

And yet the solution still worked. So why is a supposedly (doubly) invalid hosts file entry actually affecting traffic related to an IP used in it and what is the process of it doing so?

After doing a little light reverse engineering, it appears that Assassin's Creed attempts to connect to a host called gconnect.ubi.com. For some reason, having resolved gconnect.ubi.com to an IP address, it then attempts to do a reverse lookup of that IP address - 203.132.26.155 - back to a name (perhaps to verify that it's got the right IP address?). Adding the entry to the Windows hosts file means that 203.132.26.155 will resolve to 0.0.0.0 and prevent the game from doing whatever it's doing when it pauses.
Presumably, in the past, 203.132.26.155 used to resolve to gconnect.ubi.com.

I believe that this line simply redirects the IP 203.132.26.155
to an invalid domain/host name.
Any invalid name will work, so both 127.0.0.1 and 0.0.0.0 will
work, as well as many others.
If the invalid name will cause some program to issue an error
message, in this case one should use a valid host name,
such as localhost.
